# How to query Android 2.x Contacts with Emails and/or Phone Numbers?

Tags: android, email, cursor, phone-number, contactscontract

Let's brute force your garden-variety Android 2.x Visible Contact ID/Names cursor (via **ContactsContract**):

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
  Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
  new String[] { Contacts._ID, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
  Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'",
  null,
  Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC"
);
```

Is there a way to filter this to get contacts that only have at least one email and/or phone number?

I see that I can use **Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER** ... but I don't see **HAS_EMAIL** anywhere. (Tell me this isn't going to get ugly.)

Answer (score 4):

Query on the appropriate content provider `Uri`. For example, `android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email` lets you obtain email addresses, and your other columns (e.g., `IN_VISIBLE_GROUP`) are implicitly joined in.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Spinners) that demonstrates using these other content provider Uri values.

Comment: Mark comes through! Many thanks. I will take Spinners for a, um, spin. I should clarify, however. I realize I can always walk the contacts individually, but I'm trying to get the filtered list in one fell swoop.

Comment: @Joe D'Andrea: "but I'm trying to get the filtered list in one fell swoop" ...which is what the sample I supplied demonstrates. You need to take advantage of the implicit joins that the `ContactsContract` content provider supplies when you query "secondary" "tables" like `CommonDataKinds.Email`.

Comment: Perfect. That's what I'm missing - the implicit joins. (Now to try and get Eclipse to import the project!)

Comment: @Joe D'Andrea: Yeah, this is one of the reasons why I don't like content providers -- you have no way of doing joins yourself, and you're relying upon limited documentation to figure out what joins might be done on your behalf.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Sigh, yes, it's very frustrating. I think I need to botch the managedQuery just to see what the SQL is and reverse engineer from there. I'm essentially trying to write a buildEmailPhonesAdapter, that is, I want to pull contacts with an email and/or phone number, not separately. I'm sure I'm missing the implicit joins. For instance, I don't think it's enough to just add Phone.NUMBER to an Email Adapter PROJECTION - apart from probably being wrong anyway (what about folks w/phone #s but no emails?).

Comment: @Joe D'Andrea: "I want to pull contacts with an email and/or phone number, not separately" -- oof, not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I just enumerated the columns on a cursor fetched on Contacts like that:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
String[] names = c.getColumnNames();
for (String string : names) {
    Log.d("ContactList", "RC column " + string);
}
c.close();
```

The result contains `has_email`. It may be specific to the galaxy tab, though.